# using the same Dockerfile to build images with different python version

Tags: makefile, dockerfile

I have a python script that I'd want to run on 2 different containers running python 2.7 and python 3.6.

I want to use the same docker file to build 2 different images, with the difference being the python version(i.e one time it's `FROM python:3.6` and the other is `FROM python:2.7`, and do it through a makefile.

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY = all clean build run

all: build run

# DOCKER TASKS
# Build the container
build: ## Build the container for tests
        docker build -t myscript:python2.7 .
        docker build -t myscript:python3.6 .
run: ## Run container
        docker run myscript:python2.7
        docker run myscript:python3.6
```

I have a Dockerfile for building the image:
**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
RUN pip install pytest
COPY myscript.py test_regex_script.py ./

CMD ["pytest", "test_regex_script.py"]
```

Since it's the same Docker file it's tricky, I was thinking to create two different Dockerfiles each with a different python version (and all the rest the same), but was wondering if there's more elegant way to do it.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a build argument for it.

Your Dockerfile should look like this:

```
ARG VERSION=3.6

FROM python:${VERSION}

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
RUN pip install pytest
COPY myscript.py test_regex_script.py ./

CMD ["pytest", "test_regex_script.py"]
```

To build for 3.6:

```
docker build -t python-app:3.6 .
```

To build for 2.7:

```
docker build -t python-app:2.7 --build-arg VERSION=2.7 .
```

Note that 3.6 is the default version in case you don't specify one (ARG VERSION=3.6). You can also not assign a default value in which case you have to always pass a value in the build argument (--build-arg VERSION=...)

Comment: Sorry for necroposting, but shouldn't it be `FROM python:$VERSION`?

Comment: @matszwecja you are right! thanks! I submitted an edit to fix it

Answer (score 0):

you can try updating the script mentioned above like

```yaml
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=python:3.8-slim-buster

FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
RUN pip install pytest
COPY myscript.py test_regex_script.py ./

CMD ["pytest", "test_regex_script.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) is at the very top of your `Dockerfile`.

```yaml
ARG PY_VERSION=3.8
ARG NODE_VERSION=16
FROM node:$NODE_VERSION as frontend
FROM python:$PY_VERSION as backend
```

The [`FROM`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from)'s can be lower in the file.

Default (`python:3.8` and `node:16`):

```sh
docker build \
-t my-image \
-f Dockerfile \
.
```

Override Python (use `3.10` instead of `3.8`):

```sh
docker build \
-t my-image \
-f Dockerfile \
--build-arg PY_VERSION=3.10 \
.
```

Override Node:

```sh
docker build \
-t my-image \
-f Dockerfile \
--build-arg NODE_VERSION=17 \
.
```

Override Both:

```sh
docker build \
-t my-image \
-f Dockerfile \
--build-arg PY_VERSION=3.10 \
--build-arg NODE_VERSION=17 \
.
```

You can also use [buildx / `docker buildx build`](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/):

```sh
docker buildx build \
-t my-image \
-f Dockerfile \
--build-arg PY_VERSION=3.10 \
--build-arg NODE_VERSION=17 \
.
```